# Expose GPUs with "docker run --gpus" have risks?

Tags: docker, security

Are there any risks if a container is run in docker with option "--gpus" ?
For example, can the container somehow change/view the graphics running on the host machine ?

I can only find it *expose GPUs for use* on the official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#gpu), i ask because i want run untrusted images that 'need' GPUs.